# How to pass a variable from the url to a view in django?

Tags: python, django

Simple question.

How can I pass a variable from the URL to the view? I'm following the [Date Example](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/).

My view needs to arguments:

```
def hours_ahead(request, offset):
```

My url.py has this"

```
(r'^plus/\d{1,2}/$', hours_ahead),
```

I know I need to pass another argument through but I don't know how to get the number from the URL string (i.e. 'time/plus/**4**/'. Something like this?

```
(r'^plus/\d{1,2}/$', hours_ahead, offset=??),
```

Comment: Your URL only has one number.  Only one.  What is that one number?  Hours ahead or offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Named groups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in the regex

```
(r'^plus/(?P<offset>\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question clearly. Here is my shot at answering based on what I understood.

Adding a [named regex group](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) to your URL configuration should help:

```
(r'^plus/(?P<offset>\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
```

This will let you keep the existing view:

```
def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add additional variables like this:

```
(r'^plus/\d{1,2}/$', {'hours' : 5},  hours_ahead),
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

From [chapter 3 of the django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html):

> Now that we've designated a wildcard for the URL, we need a way of
>   passing that wildcard data to the view function, so that we can use a
>   single view function for any arbitrary hour offset. We do this by
>   placing parentheses around the data in the URLpattern that we want to
>   save. In the case of our example, we want to save whatever number was
>   entered in the URL, so let's put parentheses around the \d{1,2}, like
>   this:

```
(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
```

> If you're familiar with regular expressions, you'll be right at home
>   here; we're using parentheses to capture data from the matched text.