# Passing variable argument via url in django forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am developing a site based on cities and would like to pass in the city as a parameter via the url for the object creation page. What is the best way to go about this, I have been looking through the docs but can't seem to find this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to do this

[How to pass a variable from the url to a view in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583245/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-the-url-to-a-view-in-django)

In my case the variable I passed through I just added the the regex of the url in the urls.py Hope it helps.

Here is another link which is from the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls) which could help you understand urls and how to pass variables.

Comment: I figured out how to successfully pass the variable into a list view to filter the queryset but am having trouble finding a way to use a passed in variable to automatically populate a model creation form. In other words I want to be able to have an "Add Restaurant Form" that automatically recognizes the city from the urlpattern such as '^/(?P<city>[-\w]+)/restuarant/add/$'

Comment: when you go to the Add Restaurant Form you and specifying a URL right? Just pass the the id or city code along with that url?